# Jquery plugin callback on element selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll

I'm creating a plugin that works with scrolling to detect when an element is visible in the viewport. I'm trying to add a callback option that executes anything that's passed in it when an element is targeted. Below are the main parts of my plugin.

```
$.myPlugin = function(el, options) {

var base = this;

// Access to jQuery and DOM versions of element
base.$el = $(el);
base.el = el;

// Initialize
base.init = function() {
    base.options = $.extend({}, $.myPlugin.defaultOptions, options);
};

// when element is visible in the viewport 
if (base.inviewport()) {
    // Callback
    if (typeof base.options.callback === 'function') {
        base.options.callback.call(this);
    }
    return;
}

// Run initializer
base.init();

$.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        (new $.myPlugin(this, options));
    });
};

}
```

Now I'm trying to use the callback:

```
$(function() {
    $('.some-class').myPlugin({
        callback: function() {
            console.log($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

When I scroll to the element selector I'm expecting the callback to return the element with the class name `some-class` but instead it returns `window`

`[Window, jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]`

Please inform what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: you need to share the complete plugin... where is `$.myPlugin`

Comment: since you are calling `new $.myPlugin(this, options)` - `this` inside the `$.myPlugin` method refers to the jQuery object not the target element

Comment: still the complete plugin method is missing...

Comment: Creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/‎) would be useful. You can also see if the [waypoint plugin](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/ ) helps

Comment: in abstract it should be something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dNY4M/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny I added the missing code. I just left out the functions that aren't applicable to the callback option to simplify.

Comment: try changing it to `base.options.callback.call(el);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks! Using `el` works. I'll mark your answer correct if you post it!